# Как мне узнать кодировку имени файла?

Tags: windows, файлы, файловая-система

Как мне узнать кодировку имени файла?
Подскажите программы под Windows и Linux.
Также временами надо делать групповое переименование кодировки в именах и внутренностях файлов. Тоже нужна надёжная программа под   Windows и Linux.

Comment: Что Вы имеете ввиду говоря "групповое переименование кодировки"?

Comment: вопрос слишком общий. оставьте упоминание одной операционной системы (нажав [edit]), а для другой создайте новый вопрос. и, естественно, второй вопрос («также временами надо делать…») должен быть задан отдельно (для каждой интересующей операционной системы).

Comment: Под linux есть `file`.

Comment: В Windows кодировка имён файлов всегда одна — это UTF-16. В Unix-подобных системах (в том числе Linux и macOS) в подавляющем большинстве случаев используется UTF-8. Про использование других кодировок в современных ОС и ФС мне ничего не известно

Comment: Подозреваю, вы хотели задать вопрос о чём-то другом, но использовали неподходящий для вашего случая термин «кодировка имени файла»

Answer (score 0):

Про Linux не скажу, а для Windows с кодировкой все просто: все имена файловых объектов в NTFS хранятся в UTF-16.

Если же вам надо определять к какому национальному алфавиту принадлежит конкретное имя, то это надо анализировать коды символов (например, символы кириллицы имеют коды UTF-16 вида `04xx`). Смысла в этом не очень много, потому что в имени могут смешиваться символы любых алфавитов. Готовую программу для такого анализа найти будет сложно. А если писать самому, то тут в помощь только непосредственно материалы Unicode Consortium, в частности библиотека ICU.